# Replacing radio button with "selected" in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a quiz powered by jQuery (and maybe JSON), with the values stored in a database. It works fine so far, but I'd like to hide the radio buttons (CSS: display: none) and make each question look like a button (much easier to select than a tiny radio button).

However, when I do this, the following JavaScript doesn't work, and the quiz isn't scored.

```
var imgpath = "/images/sections/test/";
var jsonpath = "/2b/inc/pages/quiz-php/json/";
var jsonfile = "key";

$(document).ready(function(){
 //Make sure radio buttons are not disabled or checked (helpful when refreshing)
 $("input[type='radio']").attr("disabled", false);
 $("input[type='radio']").attr("checked", false);
 $(".submit").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //Check the quiz results
    checkQuiz();
});
//Build the json filename
jsonfile = $("#quiz").attr("rel")+".php";
});

//Load json file
function getData(update){
 $.getJSON(jsonpath+jsonfile, function(json){
 //Execute the callback
 update(json);
 }).error(function(){alert("error");});
}

function checkQuiz(){
 $(".submit").remove();
 getData(function(data){
    var ans = data.key;
    var result = {};
    $(".Question").each(function(){
        //Get the question id
        var _q = $(this).attr("id");
        //Get the selected answer class
        var _a = $("#"+_q+" input:checked").closest("li").attr("class");
        //Add the values to the result object
        result[_q] = _a;

        //Compare the selected answer with the correct answer
        if(ans[_q]==_a){
            $(this).addClass("correct");
        }else{
            $(this).addClass("wrong");
        }
    });
    //Build the feedback
    var fdbck = "You got "+$(".correct").length+" out of "+$(".Question").length+" correct.  "
    if($(".correct").length==0){
        fdbck += "Better luck next time.";
    }else if($(".correct").length>$(".Question").length/2){
        fdbck += "Good job!";
    }else{
        fdbck += "Not bad.";
    }
    $(".feedback").text(fdbck);
    $(".feedback").show();
 });
}
```

So I wondered if there's some way to record scores besides a radio button. I created a JSFiddle @ http://jsfiddle.net/9j7fz99w/6/ to illustrate how I'm using jQuery and CSS to style correct and incorrect answers. Is there a way to modify the code above to similarly recognize correct questions based on their "selection," rather than a radio button?

Comment: You can store your stats inside an array i.e: `[1,0,0,1]` ... where `1` can represent that the answer was correct. after one answers, you simply `+answ` (a boolean) and `answersArray.push(answ)` it into the array.

Comment: if it's a JSON, after you read it an Object you can simply assign a new property: `question.useranswer = value;` so you'll have your same object just with an additional property and the answer value inside it as the quiz advances.

Comment: @ Roko: I Googled answersArray.push(answ) and kind of get it, but I'm confused. Imagine a quiz with just two questions: 1) What color is an apple? A. red, B. yellow, C. blue; 2) What color is a banana? A. blue, B. purple, C. yellow. The answers to these two questions are A. and C. What would the resulting "push" array look like?

Comment: Regarding your second comment, when you say "as the quiz advances," do you mean that method only works when displaying one question at a time? My quizzes will tentatively display all ten (or 25) questions at once. The user will select all the answers, then click the Submit button.

Comment: Than create an array `quiz = [{},{},{}]` where `{}` are objects like `{question: "bla", answers: ["ans 1","ans 2","ans 3"], userchoice : ""}`

Comment: with the above example you can: loop the array and create the whole quiz form, but also, as the user answers you can fill the current question's `userchoice` with the selected radio value.

Comment: i'll create a quick demo how to do it. gimme a min

Comment: *"much easier to select than a tiny radio button"* - Are you aware that clicking on a `<label>` element associated with a radio button  will select the radio button?

Comment: @ nnnnn - Are you sure? When I click outside the radio button, the scoring script doesn't work. I'll try it again to make sure...

Comment: I'm completely sure. I've implemented it in multiple projects tested on multiple browsers and never had a problem. And it works for me in *your* demo fiddle. Clicking on the "Wrong answer" or "Right answer" text selects the appropriate radio button.

Comment: @ nnnnnn - You're right; good catch. So I'm guessing the problem is with my JavaScript file, which interprets things differently if you click outside the radio button. I now have a working example online @ http://www.govwa.org/test/one.php Question #2 doesn't work, but if you click the radio button for the first answer to Question #1, then click Submit, it says you got one right. Refresh the page and do it again, and it reports 0 right.

Comment: I meant to say, if you refresh the page, then click the same answer OUTSIDE the radio button, it reports 0 right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a small example using a JS questions Array with Objects

```js
var $quizEl = $("#quizEl");
var $submit = $("#submit");
var quiz = [
  {                 // obj
    "Q" : "What color is the Sun?",
    "A" : ["Red", "Black", "Yellow"],
    "C" : 2
  },{
    "Q" : "What color is an Elephant?",
    "A" : ["Gray", "Blue", "Yellow"],
    "C" : 0         // zero indexed! 
  },{
    "Q" : "What color is the Sea?",
    "A" : ["Fuchsia", "Blue", "Gold"],
    "C" : 1
  }
];
var qNum = quiz.length;

// FUNCTION THAT CREATES AND APPENDS AN `UL` TO `DIV #quizEl`
function generateQuestion( obj, idx ) {
  var html = "<h2>"+ obj.Q +"</h2><ul>";
  for (var i=0; i<obj.A.length; i++) {
    html += "<li>"+
      "<label>"+
      "<input type='radio' name='"+ idx +"' value='"+i+"'>"+
      obj.A[i] +"</label>"+
      "</li>";
  }
  $quizEl.append( html+"</ul>" );
}

// GENERATE ALL QUESTIONS:
for(var i=0; i<qNum; i++) {
  generateQuestion( quiz[i], i ); // quiz[i] is the {QAC} object
}

$quizEl.on("change", ":radio", function(){ // Record User choice (U property)
  quiz[this.name].U = this.value; // set 0,1,2 to the new U property {QACU}
});


$submit.on("click", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  
  console.log( quiz ); // To test how it looks
  
  // Check if user answered them all:
  for(var i=0; i<qNum;i++){
    if(!quiz[i].hasOwnProperty("U")){ // User did not answered if "U" property doesn't exists
      return alert("Please,\nanswer the question "+ (i+1) +":\n"+ quiz[i].Q );
    }else{ // Add classes...
      $("ul").eq(i).find(":checked").closest("li")
      .addClass( +quiz[i].U === quiz[i].C ? "correct":"wrong");
    }
  }
  // Finally colour them!
  $(".correct").css({background:"green"});
  $(".wrong").css({background:"red"});
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="quizEl"></div>
<input id="submit" type="submit">
```